# Customizing moderncv numbering pages style

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, moderncv

So, I was doing something like this:

`\cfoot{\color{color2}\itshape John~~Doe}`

to get my name centered on bottom of each page. Now I'd like to have it in one line with page number. Now it looks like that:

```
                 PAGE/PAGE
John Doe
```

And I'd like to look it like this:

```
John Doe         PAGE/PAGE
```

My name, and numbered page in one line. With `\lfoot` or `\cfoot` I can't achieve that.

Also, how to start page numbering from page 2? `\setcounter{page}{2}` does not works. Thanks in advance.

Minimal working example (`\newpage`'s were added ONLY to force page numbers - I don't use them in original document!):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{orange}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
%\title{}
\address{street}{postcode city}
\mobile{+4~(11)~311~111}
%\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}
%\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{mail@yahoo.com}
%\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\extrainfo{additional info}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture.png}
%\quote{}

\cfoot{\color{color2}\itshape John~~Doe}

\begin{document}

\section{Expirience}

\subsection{My work}
\cvcomputer{One}{Bla, Bla, Bla}{Two}{Bla,Bla,Bla}

\newpage

\section{Foreign Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{English}{Fluent}{Some description here}

\newpage

\section{Other Skills}
\cvitemwithcomment{Computers}{Very good}{Some description here}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems to be a bug of `moderncv`. `moderncv` puts the page number in a `\parbox` but doesn't justify them vertical. So you can use the following redefinition:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\nopagenumbers}{\@displaypagenumbersfalse}
\AtEndPreamble{%
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \if@displaypagenumbers%
      \@ifundefined{r@lastpage}{}{%
        \ifthenelse{\pageref{lastpage}>1}{%
          \settowidth{\pagenumberwidth}{\color{color2}\addressfont\itshape\strut\thepage/\pageref{lastpage}}%
          \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
            \fancyfoot[r]{\parbox[t]{\pagenumberwidth}{\color{color2}\addressfont\itshape\strut\thepage/\pageref{lastpage}}}}% the parbox is required to ensure alignment with a possible center footer (e.g., as in the casual style)
          \pagestyle{plain}}{}}%
      \AtEndDocument{\label{lastpage}}\else\fi}}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This worked like a charm. And how to force moderncv to start counting pages from page 2? I think I could e-mail author of moderncv to fix this bug, of course by pointing him to your message.

Comment: @Teddy: Try at the first page `\thispagestyle{empty}`. It removes all headers and footers. If you want to suppress only the page numbering you have to set \fancyfoot.

Comment: Bingo! Perfect. :) `\thispagestyle{empty}` was what I needed.

Comment: I've e-mailed autor of moderncv about this. It seems that we still have no official fix for this. I'd be very happy if I could remove above code suggested by Marco from my .tex document.

Comment: I added this to my preamble and produced no effect. Still get the regular page numbering without "John Doe". Anything that needs deactivating on the regular moderncv template?