# Page numbers with moderncv package on MacTeX 2014 don't show

Tags: page-numbering, moderncv

I am running OS X Yosemite Beta 6 with MacTeX 2014. In general everything seems to be working, however, when I create a resume with moderncv with more that one page the page numbers are not displayed on the right hand side of the footer. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[sans, letterpaper,10pt]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\name{John}{Doe}
%\title{}
\address{street}{postcode city}
\mobile{+4~(11)~311~111}
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{mail@yahoo.com}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\extrainfo{additional info}
% \photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture.png}
%\quote{}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Experience}

\subsection{My work}
\cvcomputer{One}{Bla, Bla, Bla}{Two}{Bla,Bla,Bla}

\newpage

\section{Foreign Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{English}{Fluent}{Some description here}

\newpage

\section{Other Skills}
\cvitemwithcomment{Computers}{Very good}{Some description here}

\end{document}
```

I have also tried to compile the code with pdflatex, xelatex, and lualatex and they don't seem to have any effect on the behaviour of the moderncv.

I know similar questions have come here, but I didn't see a resolution being offered. People have suggested using `\rfoot`, but since the page numbers are defined in moderncv, I would like to find what goes wrong in my file.

Thanks,

Hooman

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  Using `\rfoot{}` as you suggested does indeed work:  `\rfoot{Page \thepage}`. If you also want a total count of the pages you can use `\usepackage{lastpage}` and `\rfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}`.  Or, perhaps add that as the additional info: `\extrainfo{Page\ \thepage of \pageref{LastPage}}`.

Comment: Try the solution at [Customizing moderncv numbering pages style](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52723/customizing-moderncv-numbering-pages-style) and if that works for you perhaps we should close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: I used the solution provided in [Customizing moderncv numbering pages style](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52723/customizing-moderncv-numbering-pages-style) and it still doesn't print the page numbers. While using the \rfoot{} solves the problem, my question is mainly that why this doesn't work out of the box. The package is supposed to put page numbers at the footer. What is the cause that they don't show up?

Comment: Also I noticed that the solution provided there was for vertical justification of page numbers with the contents of the `cfoot`. This means that they were getting the page numbers. In my case, unless I used the workaround of `\rfoot{Page\ \thepage}`, I don't get a page number.

Comment: Where exactly do you want the page number?

Comment: The page numbers are supposed to show up in the right side of footer. If you take a look at the [moderncv casual style example on ctan](http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template_casual_orange.pdf), you can see where the page numbers are supposed to show up.

Comment: @PeterGrill Seems you didn't get a ping.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Do you have two accounts? If so, you should ask a moderator to merge them. As far as this question goes, I only have a solution to make it work and that is to add `\usepackage{lastpage}` and then use `\rfoot{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}`. I don't have an answer to why this is not the default behaviour.

Comment: @PeterGrill I just skimmed the unanswered questions and thought you would provide an answer swooping it off the list.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't know why this is needed (seems as it should be the default behavior), but to obtain the page numbering you can add

```
\usepackage{lastpage}
\rfoot{\addressfont\itshape\textcolor{gray}{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}
```

which yields:

[image]

Comment: As you said this should be the default behavior and according to the examples of moderncv package, the page numbers should appear there without the need for these two lines of code. However, I used this workaround and it worked for me.

Comment: What do I have to change to get the page numbering centered?
Never mind \cfoot does the trick

Comment: For some reason `xcolor` complains: `Error: undefined color 'true'`. Using `\pageref*` instead of `\pageref` works.

Comment: @AnthonyLabarre: Sounds like you should post a question including a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.  Sounds like a bug to me, but not sure without being able to reproduce it.

Comment: @PeterGrill: I just discovered that the error was caused by the option `linkcolor=true` in `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,colorlinks,linkcolor=true]{moderncv}`. This option does not cause any error if I remove the two lines you gave in your answer, however. Would you still prefer a new question?

Comment: @AnthonyLabarre: Seems like it was not related to the code in the answer but in the `linkcolor=true`. As `linkcolor` is not a boolean it was expecting an actual color to use. So, no longer seems like a bug