# Change page numbering style in moderncv document

Tags: errors, header-footer, page-numbering, moderncv

I am working with a

```
\moderncvstyle{casual}
```

template to create my CV. The template includes automatic page numbering, which is styled like this: 1/5, 2/5, 3/5 ....

I don't want this style, I just want plain numbers for each page, like this: 1, 2, 3

However, there is no indication where I can modify the page numbering style.

I can turn off page numbering by using

```
\nopagenumbers{}
```

but that's all I can do.

I have tried

```
\pagenumbers{plain}
```

which causes the error:

```
)) (./moderncvcolorblue.sty)
./main.tex:24:Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \pagenumbers

l.24 \pagenumbers
    {Plain}
uncomment to sup....%
?
```

I also looked through the moderncvcolorblue.sty file and found nothing that indicates page numbers in any way. Equally so for the other sty files I searched.

Please do you have any ideas how I can modify the page number style?

Many thanks.

Comment: You need to read `moderncv.cls`. There you'll find `\thepage/\pageref{lastpage}` which produces the page number from the total number of pages.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}` for example in the preamble of the document should do, or, if available, `\pagenumbering{arabic}` right at the document start

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, the OP wants to change the format defined on that page style.

Comment: @Sigur: the `\renewcommand` style should do, `\pagenumbering{arabic}` as well or am I completely misled?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, since the class is making use of `\thepage/\pageref{lastpage}` inside the page style I guess that your suggestion will not change the effect `1/5`...

Comment: @Sigur: I am just testing it, used that class not really before... I'll have a look inside

Comment: @Sigur: I handle it over to you... I don't understand the `moderncv` stuff ;-)

Comment: Strangely enough I don't get the page numbers, while I did a few months ago...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why, but I don't get the page numbers printed (although they should be there).

For a reference of the issue, see [Page numbers with moderncv package on MacTeX 2014 don't show](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/207374/27635).

I assume that you have some packages older than mines.

Anyway, to have the numbers as you want them in the `moderncv` style, add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\nopagenumbers
\AtEndPreamble{%
  \AtBeginDocument{%
          \newlength{\pagenumberwidth}%
          \settowidth{\pagenumberwidth}{\color{color2}\addressfont\itshape\thepage}%
          \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
            \fancyfoot[r]{\parbox[b]{\pagenumberwidth}{\color{color2}\pagenumberfont\thepage}}}
          \pagestyle{plain}}}
```

MWE (excerpt of the template)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\moderncvstyle{casual}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'


% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the optional "type" of the phone can be "mobile" (default), "fixed" or "fax"
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}                        % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[twitter]{jdoe}                             % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[github]{jdoe}                              % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

\nopagenumbers
\AtEndPreamble{%
  \AtBeginDocument{%
          \newlength{\pagenumberwidth}%
          \settowidth{\pagenumberwidth}{\color{color2}\addressfont\itshape\thepage}%
          \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
            \fancyfoot[r]{\parbox[b]{\pagenumberwidth}{\color{color2}\pagenumberfont\thepage}}}
          \pagestyle{plain}}}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 2}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation when the line wraps?}

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5\cite{book1}}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @Sigur - I investigated the `moderncv.cls` file but could not find `\thepage/\pageref{lastpage}` There was only a reference to `\hypersetup`

Comment: @Andrew Swann - yes this works, I get the page numbers as per your example. Thanks!

Comment: yep, this is the way I went because it's in the style of the moderncv{casual}. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In the standard casual template there are no page numbers.  Anyway, regardless you can add simple page numbers by putting

```
\fancyfoot[r]{\thepage}
```

just after `\begin{document}`.  This prints the page number in the lower right hand corner.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 

\moderncvstyle{casual}  

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}                   
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}                               
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}                        
\social[twitter]{jdoe}                             
\social[github]{jdoe}                              
\extrainfo{additional information}                 
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}               
\quote{Some quote}                                 

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\fancyfoot[r]{\thepage}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: In the standard casual template *there should be* page numbers. I don't know why, with the same package (1.5.1), I used to get page numbers a few time ago, but I don't get them anymore... See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/207374/27635